# Redirect console output to the end of a file C++ using ofstream

Tags: c++, ofstream, tcpdump

I want to add new out put from a buff to the end of a file `rst.txt` using ofstream.
My problem is that every new entry erases the file containt.

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <fstream>

    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        FILE *in;


        char buff[512];




        while(1)
        {
            //if(!(in = popen("tcpdump -i wlan0 -e -c 1 -vvv /home/pi/wifi", "r")))
            if(!(in = popen(" sudo tcpdump -i wlan0 -e -c 1 'type mgt subtype probe-req' -vvv", "r")))
                return 1;

            fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in);

            pclose(in);

            std::istringstream iss;

            iss.str(buff);

            std::string mac_address;
            std::string signal_strength;

            std::string info;
            while(iss >> info)
            {
        if( info.find("SA") != std::string::npos )
                    mac_address = info.substr(3);

                if( info.find("dB") != std::string::npos )
                    signal_strength = info;


            }
            ofstream file;
            file.open("rst.txt");
            streambuf* sbuf=cout.rdbuf();
            cout.rdbuf(file.rdbuf());
            cout<<"file"<< endl;

            cout << "      ADRESSE MAC     : " << mac_address << "     " ;
            cout << "      SIGNAL STRENGTH : " << signal_strength << "  " << endl;
        }

         return 0;
    }
```

Is there a way to redirect the output to the end of a file ?
Is there any way better than ofstream ?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open look at the `mode` parameter

Comment: `file.open("rst.txt", std::ios::app);` appends to end of file

Comment: Why do you change the `rdbuf` of `cout`? You can just use `file` instead.

Comment: 1/ `tcpdump` is not involved in your question here (it just happens to be the command you want to run), please remove the tag

Comment: 2/ You cannot `sudo` in a `popen()` lile this, it will not work, `sudo` require interaction from a terminal/pty. What you need to do is run **your** C++ program under `sudo` (privilege will be inherited by its child popen'ed process).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append from 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/open/

```
ofstream file;
file.open ("rst.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
```

**Update**
To fulfill the request in the comments.

Add a variable `previous_mac_address`

```
 [...]
 string previous_mac_address = "";
 while(1)
 {
 [...]
```

Then before printing compare the `previous_mac_address` and `mac_address`

```
 [...]
 if ( previous_mac_address != mac_address )
 {
     cout << "      ADRESSE MAC     : " << mac_address << "     " ;
     cout << "      SIGNAL STRENGTH : " << signal_strength << "  " << endl;
    previous_mac_address = mac_address; 
 }
 else
    cout << ", " << signal_strength << "  " << endl;

 [...]
```

Comment: thank you @Matteo it works. I have one last question: is there a way to put all `signal_strength` which are related to one `mac_address` on the same line ?

Comment: Or simply use std::ios::out && std::ios::app

Comment: @Cyrine Can you give me a sample of the output of your command line?

Comment: @Matteo This is what I get in my `rst.txt`file :  ADRESSE MAC : f0:25:b7:15:3b:b0   SIGNAL STRENGTH : -69dB 
ADRESSE MAC : 6e:81:e3:7f:4b:67   SIGNAL STRENGTH : -43dB 
ADRESSE MAC : 6e:81:e3:7f:4b:67   SIGNAL STRENGTH : -41dB

Comment: Is there a way to have : ADRESSE MAC : 6e:81:e3:7f:4b:67   SIGNAL STRENGTH : -43dB,-41dB

Comment: @Cyrine Would you accept my answer, pressing the 'green tick' (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @Matteo making a test on an existing mac_address didn't work, because every new entry is unrelated with the previous output I already have.

Comment: @Matteo If you don't mind helping me the a substr of another info here you find the link [http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11594725]

Comment: @Cyrine If you would like to update the file "rst.txt" with new value retrieved for 'tcpdump', the situation is more complex. You need to parse both the output of 'tcpdump' and "rst.txt", and join the results. To pass a file, you should use an external service like http://pastebin.ca/upload.php